Using Eigen to perform a convolution with stride
I am trying to get Eigen to perform a convolution operation with a stride (for a convolutional neural network). I know that Eigen has a convolve function which you can perform on a tensor:
input.convolve(filter, dimensions) 

There is no parameter to provide a stride value.
I know that Eigen also has a stride function which returns a view of a tensor applying a certain stride. However, this isn't (I don't think) the same as applying a stride to a convolution. I wondered whether you can apply the stride function to the input and then call convolve but I don't think that result in a proper convolution with stride.
Does anyone know how to apply a convolution with stride (except for manually writing the convolution function rather than relying upon Eigen's convolve function)?
I have noticed that there is a "extract_image_patches" function which returns a list of areas of an input - is this used instead of the convolve function?
Thanks
I have looked on Stackoverflow and Cross Validated but cannot see this answered anywhere. A similar question was asked here but not answered.
